# How strong is the tripod mount on the bottom of a DSLR?

Tags: equipment-damage, camera-straps, tripod-socket

I'm looking at getting a sling-style strap for my camera (Canon 60D) but the one thing I keep wondering is if the tripod mount is strong enough to "hang" the camera from.  I've seen some discussions of this, but no clear answer.

Are the any known issues with hanging a camera from the tripod mount?  Would hanging it from one of the side lugs be stronger/safer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mount on the bottom of the camera is plenty strong. I carry a 5D and 1Ds Mk III around with my [Black Rapid](http://www.blackrapid.com/) all the time and have had no problem. Just make sure you have the screw snugged down and check it periodically.

I really can't recommend these sling straps enough. I have a Black Rapid, so I haven't tried any others, but it's really made it a lot easier on my neck and back to carry heavy cameras and long lenses around.

Comment: Yup, I have a DIY Black Rapid style and I can't imagine ever going back.

Comment: Question is, is it strong enough to hold a camera and a heavy tele lens??

Comment: @ysap - I have the dual camera version. With the strap attached to my battery grip, I carry a K-5 with a Sigma 120-400mm lens attached with no problems and that's while hiking. It can do it, but you can also transfer it over to the tripod collar on the lens too if you're worried, either works.

Comment: I find myself deliberately I pushing the camera over to my side so it's less obtrusive and I can keep a hand on the grip if I have to move fast. I've found it's easier to get through crowded markets and such with this arrangement than regular straps. But if you're toting a 400mm lens, crowds are probably not your biggest problem :)

Comment: I have the BlackRapid RS-4 attached to a Canon 60D. They've been attached to each other for over a year, and even though I check the connection periodically, it has *never* actually required any tightening. I have various lenses, including a weighty 24-105 L lens. I'm also doing a my second 365 project so I use my camera every single day. BR rules and the tripod socket is plenty strong enough.

Comment: Didn't experience any problems with a 100-400mm L on a 7D. That's a 1.380Kg (49oz) tele-lens. 70-200L IS USM II is a tad heavier, but the current weight champion seems to be the 28-300L (1.7kg - 60 oz). I imagine the future 200-400 f4 L is even heavier.

Answer (score 5):

The whole socket on my 5D3 Came away today. It popped out of the body whilst I was adjusting a tripod head. I use a Black Rapid shoulder strap. I can only assume that has weakened it over time. Just glad I had it in my hands at the time.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is a revelation. The screw is not integrated on a metal frame, just to the plastic.

Comment: @Rafael Actually there is a very thin rim of metal around the screw housing that connects to the metal base. If you look in the hole you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

pretty good, in short. as long as you know how to use it properly. for example if you mount the head in the camera body instead of tripod collar (when you have 70-200mm f/2.8 IS II attached) it will not work good.

every lens with higher weight comes with a tripod collar, otherwise you can go look for a third party one.

so use it properly and it will serve your need for quite a long time flawlessly.

Comment: I've used the Black Rapid effortlessly with the 70-200mm Canon lens. It's really heavy but it works as it is supposed to. As I said in a previous comment, the key for me is adjusting the strap so the camera rests on my hip instead of dangling in space. And that's the advantage of these straps over a traditional camera strap anyhow.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the safety feature I have added to my cheap but good $ 7 shoulder sling strap from evil bay.
Note: I checked for the strength of the 1" Nylon Strap + the Carabiner + the Plastic Strap Retainer/Adjuster. The L-Plate metal is thick and sturdy and attaches to the tripod socket through a large Thumb Screw.

Attach a large dia strong Key Ring through the carabiner and its metal D- Rectangle through which the strap passes. String a strong Nylon cord through the Key Ring & the neck strap lug on your camera. Use a quick release clip if you wish, should you want to release the strap quickly from the camera.

Comment: While this is decent advice, it doesn't answer the question, "How strong is the tripod mount on a DSLR?"